# How can you resolve Oozie error JA009

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I am running a simple Oozie workflow on Cloudera VM. The sub-workflow calls a shell script which sends a test email. However, I am getting the JA009 error:
(`JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.`).

I have already changed `mapreduce.framework.name` from `yarn` to `classic` in the following places:

```
/etc/oozie/conf/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml
/etc/oozie/conf/hadoop-config.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml
```

Also, in `/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh` I changed:

```
"export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce"
```

to:

```
"export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce"
```

Is there anything I am missing? Yarn is not showing up in `hadoop fs -ls /user` (hive, pig, spark etc are). So I am assuming Yarn is not pre-installed here.